# Can't access XML node using xpath (namepace issue?)

Tags: php, dom, xpath, tridion

I have a small part of a xml export from a cms called tridion and I would like to parse this information using php.

I tried using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` to access the data but fail to retrieve the required information.

For example when I try to access the node **title** from my example data I don't get any result.

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xmlFilePath);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('tcm', 'http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0');
$xpath->registerNamespace('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
$result = $xpath->query('title');
```

I believe this is a namespace issue but I don't really understand how to handle it.

This is what the export files look like (somewhat shortened for readability):

```
<PackageItem xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/ImportExport/Package/2013">
  <PrimaryBlueprintParentUrl>/webdav/Content%20%28en%29/Content/120_external%20Links/Services/EL_www%2some-domin%2Ecom.xml</PrimaryBlueprintParentUrl>
  <Data>
    <tcm:Data>
      <tcm:Title>EL_www.some-domain.com</tcm:Title>
      <tcm:Type>Normal</tcm:Type>
      <tcm:Schema xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="External Link (EL)" xlink:href="/webdav/Content/System/Schemas/Common/External%20Link%20%28EL%29.xsd" IsMandatory="false" />
      <tcm:Content>
        <externallink xmlns="uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8">
          <title>www.some-domain.com</title>
          <url xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://www.some-domain.com" />
        </externallink>
      </tcm:Content>
    </tcm:Data>
  </Data>
</PackageItem>
```

Comment: Have you tryed using simplexml_load_string. This converts the xml into an object

Comment: copy the full error message too can be helpfull

Comment: There is no error message, my xpath query simply does not return anything.

Comment: I tried using `simplexml_load_string()` as well but it seems like this function does not handle xml namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<externallink>` element just before it defines the default namespace for it and `<title>` element as `xmlns="uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8"`.  So if you define this namespace (I just use a dummy one - `d`) and then use this in your expression...

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('d', "uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8");
$result = $xpath->query('//d:title');
```

**Update...**

For the url...

```
$result = $xpath->query('//d:url');

echo $xmlDoc->saveXML($result[0]);
```

Gives...

```
<url xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://www.some-domain.com"/>
```

As this doesn't have a value as such (I've just said to output the XML of the first node found), not sure what you need out of it.

If you just want the href attribute...

```
echo $result[0]->getAttribute("xlink:href");
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. Your suggested code works well to retrieve the title information! Can you please add some information on how to get the url information as well? Seems like the namespace attached to the url attribute is causing some trouble. At least `$xpath->query('//d:url');` does not work.

Comment: I've added the URL code - it depends on what your trying to get from it?

Answer (score 1):

You missed registering aliases for the right namespaces. Here is an namespace definition for on the element `externallink` for the namespace `uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8`. The XML parser understands that node as `{uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8}externallink` and the `title` child element as `{uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8}title`. The 3 following examples all all resolve to a `title` node like that:

- `<title xmlns="uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8"/>`
- `<t:title xmlns:t="uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8"/>`
- `<el:title xmlns:el="uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8"/>`

By registering aliases on the `DOMXpath` instance you allow it to do the same for the expression.

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('e', 'uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8');
```

`e:title` -> `{uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8}title`

Xpath 1.0 has no default namespace, so you will have to register an alias for any namespace you want to use in the expression.

However `e:title` would look for child nodes only. To look at any node in the document use `//e:title`. The starting `/` anchors the expression to the document itself (and not the current context node). The second `/` changes the axis from `child` to `descendant`.
Use `string()` to cast the first matched node into a string and return it:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('e', 'uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8');
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//e:title)'));
```

Output:

```
string(19) "www.some-domain.com"
```

`DOMXpath::query()` can only return node lists, `DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return scalar values as well.

For the `xlink:href` attribute you need to register that namespace as well:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('e', 'uuid:D612E2C9-CD2E-4CD8-9FAE-3826311343A8');
$xpath->registerNamespace('xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//e:url/@xlink:href)'));
```

Output:

```
string(26) "http://www.some-domain.com"
```